# Can two mundane parents give birth to an awakened child?

Tags: lore, magic, shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun

Is it possible for two mundane parents to give birth to an awakened child in Shadowrun SR5? I've not been able to find any information about this in the core rulebook. By awakened, I mean someone possessing the magic attribute, not being a metatype other than a human.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Yes

Magic in Shadowrun is *funky*. Being magically awakened is **not** genetic, as the lore tells: two awakened parents might have only mundane kids, two mundanes might have a bunch of awakened children or none.

The information you seek for SR5 hides in the *Street Grimoire*, where the very first Chapter is titled accordingly *Born Awakened*.

If you have access to the older SR4 material, especially *Street Magic* that might be worth a shot too: Once again the very first chapter is titled tellingly *The Magical Child: Growing Up Awakened*. That chapter quotes from an in-universe pamphlet called *My Child Has the Talent: Now What?*.

Comment: Given the lore for SR in general, and that non-/metahumans just spontaneously got the magic in the first place I would say the same but with far less sourcing.